# Can't get all values from mysql table

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have this table:

```
option_values table:
option_id (FK)
value_id (PK)
classified_id (FK)
value
```

example:

```
   option_id (FK)     value_id (PK)     classified_id (FK)     value
        1                  1                   22              'Petrol'
        2                  2                   22              'Manual'
        3                  3                   22              'Black'
```

How can I retrieve and echo every value found with the classified_id=22 ?

I have tried this:

```
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM option_values WHERE classified_id=22");
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  echo $row[3]; // This displays 'Petrol'
```

But how can I also display the 'Manual', 'Black' etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this, you need to get an array of rows...they way you are doing it is giving you a single row's value in an array.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Value: %s", $row[0], $row[3]);  
}
```

Source: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM option_values WHERE classified_id=22");
while(FALSE != ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo $row[3];
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling mysql_fetch_rows twice?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM option_values WHERE classified_id=22");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
    echo $row[1];
    echo $row[2];
    echo $row[3];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and implement a helper function like so:

```
function fetch_multi_rows($query)
{
    $rows = array();

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
        $rows[] = $row;

    return $rows;
}

// Use it like this
$my_rows = fetch_multi_rows(...your query...);
foreach ( $my_rows as $row )
    echo $row[3];
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a "more object oriented" code like :)

```
// Execute the query
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM option_values WHERE classified_id=22");

// Check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No results.";
    exit;
}

// Fetch results as objects
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo "Option Id: ".$row->option_id;
    echo "Value: ".$row->value;
}

// Free results memory
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Cheers Mate!